# PostgreSQL volatile expressions and subqueries

Tags: postgresql, generate-series

In Bruce Momjian's blog post [Generating Random Data Via SQL](http://momjian.us/main/blogs/pgblog/2012.html#July_24_2012) he used the following code to generate 5 random strings:

```
SELECT
(
        SELECT string_agg(x, '')
        FROM (
                SELECT chr(ascii('a') + floor(random() * 26)::integer)
                FROM generate_series(1, 40 + b * 0) as f(g)
        ) AS y(x)
) AS result
FROM generate_series(1,5) as a(b);

              result                  
------------------------------------------
 plwfwcgajxdygfissmxqsywcwiqptytjjppgrvgb
 sjaypirhuoynnvqjdgywfsfphuvzqbbilbhakyhf
 ngtabkjfqibwahlicgisijatliuwgbcuiwujgeox
 mqtnyewalettounachwjjzdrvxbbbpzogscexyfi
 dzcstpsvwpefohwkfxmhnlwteyybxejbdltwamsx
(5 rows)
```

I wondered why 'b * 0' at line 6 is required. When I removed it, the result changed to 5 exactly similar strings which means Postgres cached the outer select expression (result)!

I could not find how expression caching is working in Postgres. According to [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xfunc-volatility.html) random() function is marked VOLATILE, so, I'd expect any expression depends on it to be volatile too.

How does expression caching work in Postgres? Is it documented anywhere? Why 'b*0' disabled the cache where random() did not?

Update:

To study the issue, I moved 'b * 0' to inside the floor() call to be at same position/level as random():

```
...
                SELECT chr(ascii('a') + floor(random() * 26 + b * 0)::integer)
                FROM generate_series(1, 40) as s(f)
...
```

The result is still not cached; different strings.

Update: Another example to show the problem

```
create sequence seq_test;

SELECT (SELECT nextval('seq_test')) FROM generate_series(1,5);

 ?column? 
----------
        1
        1
        1
        1
        1
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `random()` itself is volatile, hence you don't get strings with the same character repeated to the end.

If you look at the plans for the queries with and without `b*0` you will see:

With `b*0`:

```
 Function Scan on generate_series a  (cost=0.00..37530.00 rows=1000 width=4)
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Aggregate  (cost=37.51..37.52 rows=1 width=32)
           ->  Function Scan on generate_series  (cost=0.01..25.01 rows=1000 width=0)
```

Without `b*0`:

```
 Function Scan on generate_series a  (cost=37.52..47.52 rows=1000 width=0)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Aggregate  (cost=37.50..37.51 rows=1 width=32)
           ->  Function Scan on generate_series  (cost=0.00..25.00 rows=1000 width=0)
```

If PostgreSQL determines that the inner aggregation is not dependent on `a`, then it is evaluated once as an `InitPlan`, and the volatility or not of the expressions within are irrelevant. By introducing the dependency of the subquery on `a`, i.e. making it a correlated subquery, the evaluation must be redone for each row of `a`.

Comment: So, the planner evaluated the inner expression for each row `f` despite it is not dependent on it (correctly because it is volatile), but the outer expression is evaluated once unless it is dependent on the row! Shouldn't volatile values tint any result based on it? just like row dependency did.

Comment: the volatility of the expression will stop it being inlined, but doesn't affect how the planner arranges the query plan, which is based on whether the subselect is correlated or not.

Comment: You mean any subquery is considered STABLE unless it is dependent on row variable of the outer query! It looks like a bug to me. I'd expect volatile expressions to have a volatility viral effect on any expression or subquery. InitPlan is an optimization, it should not change the result.

Comment: "stable", "volatile" etc aren't properties of subqueries, only functions and expressions. SQL is a way of describing a query, not for defining how it is executed (although I admit this is a weak argument, and SQL is famous as a leaky abstraction)

Comment: Thanks but I'm not convinced at all. SQL or not, as expressions can contain subqueris, I expect volatility to propagate through subqueries. At least the current behavior should be documented.